# How to send values from a user interface created using HtmlService to a google spreadsheet

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have a form created using the google scripts HtmlService. I need to send the data captured once the form is submitted to a google spreadsheet, so I need to communicate withe the script on the server side. I have been following the google documentation on [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service), and from the documentation, I have come out with this sample code, at least to test the calling of a  function on the server from the html using google.script API, but it doesn't work for me:

The google Apps Script:

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log("Creating page...");
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("myFile").evaluate();
}

function test() {
  return "Testing";
}
```

And the html file:

```
<html>
  <SCRIPT>
    function evaluate(form) {
      var a = google.script.run.test();
      form.fieldName.value = a;
    }
  </SCRIPT>
    <form>
       <INPUT type = text name ="fieldName" class = "input_field" > 
       <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="buttonSubmit" Value="Guardar"    onClick='evaluate(this.form)' >
  </form>
</html>
```

¿Whats wrong with this code? Any insights on this would be really appreciated, or alternative ways to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HtmlService is used for primarily client-side functions not server based operations. 
However you can call a server function with google.script.run.FunctionName(parameter).

Example

```
<input type='button' value="Click me" onclick='google.script.run.processForm(this.parentNode)
```